# Cannot resolve AppCompatActivity from the moment I create a project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an issue here that I can't wrap my head around even with some help from colleagues or other Stack Overflow questions and answers

From the moment I create a project AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved. I already tried to:

Update Android Studio, I am on the latest version of everything
Invalidate Caches/Restart
Reinstall Android Studio and delete all my custom preferences
Delete .idea and .gradle in the project and restart
Sync Project with Gradle Files

When I go to the project structure and add dependency androidx.appcompat it solves the issue but as soon as I create another Project the problem comes back. As well I am seeing random methods not being resolved in my other projects, I didn't change anything in the past days and I tried all the above on the other projects.

Have you ever seen something similar? Happy to provide more details if needed

[MyProject Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPB3V.png)

Comment: It's good if you put the exact version of Android Studio instead of "the latest".

Answer (score 1):

**Just change your dependency in your app level gradle file:**

```
implement "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:latestVerstion"
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) you can find more info about this new class.